# Simultaneous UITextView Gesture Interactions

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `uitextview` within an `uicollectionviewcell`, covering a majority of the view.

My goal is to...
1. Scroll up and down through `uitextview` text.
2. Tap `uicollectionviewcell` to perform another function.

Right now it is either/or and not both. I tried enabling multiple touch, simultaneous gesture interaction, adding a `tapgesturerecognizer` to the `uitextview`, etc, and couldn't find any existing solutions to help. Below is some of my bare code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //do something
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //do something
}

func addTapGesture(_ cell: TestCollectionViewCell, _ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.textView.gestureRecognizers = []

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
    tap.delegate = self
    cell.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    cell.textView.isScrollEnabled = true        
}

@objc func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //do something
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: does your textView is editable?

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev neither editable nor selectable

Comment: I think you should use CollectionView didSelectMethod if TextViewCover entire cell

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev I am using that delegate method and am wondering how to use that in conjunction with the uitextview scroll

Comment: what do you want to do when user tap on TextView

Comment: rather than gesture you can use TextView textViewDidBeginEditing delegate to know if user interact with textView.but in this case you have to make textView editable